# PInvoke GetPrinterData() to get Printer Status or Errors

Tags: c#, pinvoke, zebra-printers

I'm trying to get the printer status of a Zebra label printer.  I've tried WMI, checking PrinterState, PrinterStatus, ExtendedPrinterStatus, DetectedErrorState, ExtendedDetectedErrorState, but I'm always getting values such as Unknown, or Idle.  The printer is actually out of paper, and I want to get that status.  The Windows Printers area itself is also reporting "Ready" for the status.  I installed a small Zebra Status Monitor app and it correctly reports "Out of Paper".

I think I may need to pInvoke some Windows APIs to directly query the printer.  Zebra has [this reference](https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/SOLUTIONS/7000/SO7944/en_US/Language%20MonitorRC.pdf) which shows the use of GetPrinter() and GetPrinterData().  I found [this C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283827/how-to-get-the-computer-name-and-ip-to-which-a-printer-is-connected-in-lan) of using GetPrinter() which works and includes good information, but the Status is 0 and I don't see anything that indicates Out of Paper.

Now, I'd like to try to use GetPrinterData() which that [Zebra document](https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/SOLUTIONS/7000/SO7944/en_US/Language%20MonitorRC.pdf) uses and checks for `PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT`.  Using that [GetPrinter() code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283827/how-to-get-the-computer-name-and-ip-to-which-a-printer-is-connected-in-lan) to OpenPrinter() (which is successful), I've tried a few variations of GetPrinterData().  Here's one:

```
uint pType = 0;
uint pcbNeeded = 0;
uint result1 = GetPrinterData(pHandle, "Error", out pType, null, 0, out pcbNeeded);
```

result1 is always a value of 2 and pcbNeeded is value of 0.  Even if I turn off the printer, or if the printer has paper, I always get these same values.

Any help on how to correctly pInvoke GetPrinterData() or on how to get the actual printer status would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is late for you, the post [USB communications with Zebra printers in C#](http://danielezanoli.blogspot.com/2010/06/usb-communications-with-zebra-printers.html) shows how to query the printer over USB.

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears the pinvoke.net declaration for GetPrinterData is correct but doesn't work all the time. If you change the declaration to:

```
    [DllImport("winspool.drv",
    SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint GetPrinterData(
        IntPtr hPrinter,
        string pValueName,
        out uint pType,
        out UInt32 pData,
        uint nSize,
        out uint pcbNeeded);
```

using UInt32 instead of the suggested byte[] seems to return "Error" status values as from a C++ application.