# What alternatives are available to WMI for obtaining the state of a printer?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, wmi

What options are available in C#/.NET to get the status of an installed printer? The only information we need is if the printer is on or off (we have a little indicator on the screen that says 'Printer ready' or 'Printer offline').

Our application is a small client running on an embedded PC. We've found that the WMI Windows process is running out of memory. Watching it on my development PC there appears to be a memory leak as the amount of memory it uses slowly creeps up. On an embedded device with limited memory this is unacceptable and we're finding after a couple of hours the application crashes.

Comment: have you tried to deal with the memory leaks?

Comment: It's the WMI process (wmiprvse.exe) that is increasing so it appears the memory leak is outside of my control. I'm executing the following in a loop every second:-


`ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
{
  // Checking the name of the printer and firing an event with the value of the work offline property
}`

Comment: it still could be that your code isn't releasing the other end. try using only one `ManagementObjectSearcher `

Comment: I have also tried the approach of only having a single static instance of the ManagementObjectSearcher, but I'm still seeing the WMI process continue to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to resolve the memory leak, but if you cant find it, you could always use `PInvoke` calls (specifically [`GetPrinterData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144912(v=vs.85).aspx)).  See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283827/how-to-get-the-computer-name-and-ip-to-which-a-printer-is-connected-in-lan/3283918#3283918) (Note: There are also WMI posts that could help you compare what you have and see if you can find the memory leak)